# Как реализовывается вид товара?

Tags: php, yii2

Привет ребята как в yii2 реализовывается вид товара плитка, таблица и список, как правильно сформировать ссылку

```
сама ссылка http://site.ru/blog/index?id=23
<a href="?grid"><?= Html::img('/web/images/icon-view-grid-h.png') ?></a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Нет такого функционала из коробки в Yii2. По умолчанию генерируются гриды для просмотра списка объектов, если вы хотите переключаться между гридом и списком - то вам нужно самому полностью писать этот функционал и соответственно ссылку можно создавать какую пожелаете.

Comment: а не подскажите как правильно сформировать ссылку, я не могу понять как сделать ссылку, саму проверку я уже сам сделаю???

Comment: @Uman вы хотите её сформировать средствами Yii2? Не пойму суть вопроса, формируется простой url так же как и без использования фреймворка

Comment: напишите пример, не могу взять в толк с утра?

Comment: @Uman пример чего? Вашей ссылки? `http://site.ru/blog/index?id=23?type=grid` я бы вот так как то делал

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="/blog/<?= $var->id ?>"><?= Html::img("@web/images/icon-view-grid-h.png") ?></a>
```